# jQuery: ":checked" always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 
 function WhichOneIsChecked(){
 var Item1 = ""; var Item2 = ""; var Item3 = "";
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"][name="gun"]:checked')) {
        Item1 = "مسدس";
    } if ($('input[type="checkbox"][name="phone"]:checked')) {
        Item2 = "هاتف";
    }
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"][name="car"]:checked')) {
        Item3 = "سيارة";
    }
    $("#p").html(Item1 + Item2 + Item3);
        
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="ml-1">سيارة</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="car" />
                <label class="ml-1">هاتف</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name="phone" />
                <label class="ml-1">مسدس</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name="gun" />
                <p id="p"></p>
                <a onclick='WhichOneIsChecked()'> click me</a>
```

My Problem is that if i checked one check box . 
in javascript it gives me that all checkboxes are checked

```
 <label class="ml-1">سيارة</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="car" />
        <label class="ml-1">هاتف</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="phone" />
        <label class="ml-1">مسدس</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="gun" />

   <script>var Item1 = ""; var Item2 = ""; var Item3= "";
    if ($('input[name="gun"]:checked')) {
        Item1 = "مسدس";
    } if ($('input[name="phone"]:checked')) {
        Item2 = "هاتف";
    }
    if ($('input[name="car"]:checked')) {
        Item3 = "سيارة";
    }
console.log(Item1 + Item2 + Item3);</script>
```

if i check only one of these three checkboxes ; in javascript it gives me that check boxes are checked

Comment: just use id for element then use if ($('#your_element').is(':checked')) {

Comment: i have tried it before it result the same thing

Comment: I believe this might be a duplicate - sufficient answers can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery
The comment above is one of them, also 
`$('#id_your_element').prop('checked')` should do

Comment: @ErikReder the one of id i  and (is) have tried it before . i will try the (prop) and then answer you

Comment: A good way to see if checked in jQuery: `$(element).is(':checked')`

Comment: `$('input[name="car"]:checked')` returns a jQuery **object**, even if the selector doesn't match anything. *Any* **object** cast to a Boolean (like in your if-condition) is always `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **id** for every element then check with this : **$('#phone').is(':checked')**

```js
        
        
         
 function WhichOneIsChecked(){
 var Item1 = ""; var Item2 = ""; var Item3= "";
            if ($('#gun').is(':checked')) {
                Item1 = "مسدس";
            } if ($('#phone').is(':checked')) {
                Item2 = "هاتف";
            }
            if ($('#car').is(':checked')) {
                Item3 = "سيارة";
            }
        console.log(Item1 + Item2 + Item3);
    $("#p").html(Item1 + Item2 + Item3);
        
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="ml-1">سيارة</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="car" />
                <label class="ml-1">هاتف</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  id="phone" />
                <label class="ml-1">مسدس</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  id="gun" />
                
                 <p id="p"></p>
                <a onclick='WhichOneIsChecked()'> click me</a>
```

Comment: I have tried before this and it give me the same result

Comment: @markdibe I added run code snippet for checking , please check with it

Comment: @markdibe probably you are doing something wrong. Because I tested it and it works

Comment: yea it works my problem is if i havent checked the first one m bu i checked the second it doesnt' work with me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name in all option and use the desired function

```
<label class="ml-1">سيارة</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" />
    <label class="ml-1">هاتف</label>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="item" />
    <label class="ml-1">مسدس</label>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="item" />
    <p id="p"></p>
    <a onclick='WhichOneIsChecked()'> click me</a>

     function WhichOneIsChecked(){
            var checklist="";
            $.each($("input[name='item']:checked"), function () {
                checklist+=($(this).val())+" ";
            });
            $("#p").html(checklist);       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to use `prop()` function.

Comment: your answer seems to be helpful, but it lacks formatting also explanation why it's better. We cannot just take your word for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be a duplicate - sufficient answers can be found here: stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/… 
From that,

```
 $('#id_your_element').prop('checked')
```

should do